# Mathematica 10 DateObject to TimeObject quirk

Tags: datetime, wolfram-mathematica, type-conversion

If I create a list like this:

```
x = {TimeObject[DateObject[{2015, 09, 9, 01, 01, 01}]], 
     TimeObject[DateObject[{2000, 01, 1, 09, 09, 09}]]}
```

(I cannot post images here but the list contains TimeObjects only, for sure.)

Then this works fine:

```
x[[1]] < x[[2]]
True
```

Then, if I import like this:

```
passageInOrOut = Import["/tmp/foo.csv", "DateStringFormat" -> 
    {"Year", "Month", "Day", "-", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}];
```

(The file looks like this; dates and times separated by "-")

```
    20150804-174137
    20150804-184024
    20150804-184629
    20150804-202336
    20150805-040914
    20150805-041904
```

Then I get a list of DateObjects, as I wanted (and I presume the times are there as well.)
Later on I want to use the times only, so I try this:

```
TimeObject[passageInOrOut[[6]]] < TimeObject[passageInOrOut[[1]]]
```

And get this (but as icons and text):

```
TimeObject[{Wed 5 Aug 2015}] < TimeObject[{Tue 4 Aug 2015}]
```

...when I expected "True", since I want to compare the clock times only.

I have beaten the shit out of "passageInOrOut", with every mathematica spell I have found here or elsewhere, but I cannot get anything else than the above result, or error messages.

Since the file is quite large I'm looking for a `Map` solution or something, but first I need to know how to convert those objects. Can anyone help?

System info:

```
Version:
    10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)
ReleaseID:
    10.0.2.0 (5206630, 2014120404)
PatchLevel:
    0
Language:
    English
Character Encoding:
    UTF-8
System Character Encoding:
    UTF-8
Time Zone:
    2
Initialization Files Loaded:
file://localhost/Users/xxx/Library/Mathematica/Kernel/init.m
file://localhost/Users/xxx/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/WolframAlphaClient-2.2.2015060408/Kernel/WolframAlphaClient.m
file://localhost/Users/xxx/Library/Mathematica/ApplicationData/Parallel/Preferences/Preferences.m
```

Comment: I think the problem lies with your import. Do `FullForm[passageInOrOut[[6]]]` you will see the time data has been lost.

Comment: Thank you agentp, you found the problem! I didn't know about FullForm[] -there are sooo many things in Mathematica :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you need to resort to manually parsing the string. Try this:

```
passageInOrOut = 
   DateObject[
    Table[ ToExpression@
        StringTake[#, p],
          {p, {{1, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}}}]
              ] & /@ Import["/tmp/foo.csv"][[All, 1]]
```

This seems to work too, perhaps a little cleaner:

```
DateObject@
   DateList[{#, {"Year", "Month", "Day", "-", "Hour", "Minute", 
          "Second"}}] & /@ Import["/tmp/foo.csv"][[All, 1]]
```